# How to insert sigma symbol in tableau worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

can we insert sigma symbol in tableau worksheet along with the data that is coming from the table e.g. one of the tiles is displaying 3.7 and i want sigma symbol appeneded with the value. i do not want to use a static image .

Comment: You can just copy paste the symbols from the internet,`Tableau` allows to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using ALT Codes you can write a sigma symbol. Click the Text pill then the three dots to edit the label. Press ATL + 228. 
[image: Sigma symbol]

Comment: upvote for alt codes didn't knew that but you can also copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

you can also go to **format for particular measure** then

PANE>numbers>numbers Custom>prefix or Suffix add Sigma symbol.

thanks